# Как отменить вывод ошибки в консоль, если не найдено изображение?

Tags: javascript, html

Такой код выводит ошибку в консоль:
Если он не нашел картинку то подменяет её на другую. Однако выводит сообщение об ошибке (404 (Not Found)). Можно ли указать на то, что это не ошибка?

```
<img src="image.jpeg" onerror=" this.src='new_img.jpeg'">
```

Comment: У меня в консоль такой код ничего не выводит — ни в Chrome, ни в Firefox

Comment: onerror выполняется при возникновении ошибки, поэтому у тебя сначала вылетает ошибка, потом только выполняется это событие. Никак нельзя сказать что это не ошибка.

Comment: У меня за минуту наволило 15000  ошибок

Comment: @Air примерно поэтому я убрал сниппет :)

Comment: @andreymal Я  так и понял...А пока  вопрос правил, потом у себя попробовал... Но ты меня уже опередил))) Правил обратно

Comment: @andreymal, кстати спасибо еще раз за ответ на мой вопрос...  Он мне очень помог... Кстати через пару дней получишь от меня еще 300 баллов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Нет, невозможно избежать ошибки 404 в консоли**, если вы не вызовете скрипт с сервера для проверки существования файла.

Вы можете отловить ошибку, но она все еще будет отображаться в консоль, поэтому **возможен только перехват повторной ошибки**.

Answer (score 0):

### Решение

*Обнули ошибку:*

```
this.onerror=null;
```

И прикрепи картинку какую хочешь.

### Пример

```html
<img src="invalid_link" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';"
>
```

Comment: У меня выводится ошибка.
GET https://stacksnippets.net/invalid_link 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @manking ну первая ошибка проходит пока новое изображение не загружено, но в цикл не уходит